# How to prevent uncessary rebuild for GIF in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, gif

I wanna show some gif in profile but when I try all state is rebuild. My profile picture is on another stateless widget.

So archicature is like:

> ProfilePageWidget(statefull) -> Column ->
> ProfilePhotoWidget(stateless)

Here dev tool [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/FiYinTP0Q3M)

Here my ProfilePhotoWidget:

```
class ProfilePictureWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? profilePicture;
  final double profilePhotoWidth;
  final bool isSelfProfile;
  const ProfilePictureWidget(
      {Key? key, this.profilePicture, required this.profilePhotoWidth, required this.isSelfProfile})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: profilePhotoWidth,
      width: profilePhotoWidth,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: profilePhotoWidth,
            width: profilePhotoWidth,
            child: Image.network(
              "https://media.giphy.com/media/mk22aynQZXLUstGGMC/giphy.gif",
              isAntiAlias: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: SmoodyNetworkImage(
              imageURL: profilePicture ?? "https://images.smoody.app/users/default.png",
              isCached: isSelfProfile,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is a method that belongs to the `State<T extends StatefulWidget>` class. And when you call `setState` inside a `StatefulWidget`, it will always rebuild the whole Widget in which it was called.

So you have two options:

- A harder way: try to convert `ProfilePhotoWidget` into a `StatefulWidget` and isolate the `setState` which is required to update the photo inside this widget;
- An easier way: don't use `setState` in your `ProfilePageWidget`. Instead, you can use `ValueNotifier` and `ValueListenableBuilder`, which will only rebuild what's inside this builder when you update the `ValueNotifier`. Another option is to use `ChangeNotifier` but I think `ValueNotifier` is easier.

Comment: This is not about setState. I dont use any setstate. Only I put gif to network image.

Comment: So you need to provide more details. Even by looking at the video you posted it's impossible to see the rebuild